# how to solve this type of probability question

Tags: probability

[image]
the answer is D,P and Q are not mutually exclusive because they dont have a disjoint set

Comment: Well, if $P,Q$ were mutually exclusive, no X's would be in the box common to both, no? If you want some more help, it might be best to [edit] some context into your post, such as your understanding of the problem and specific difficulties you're having

Comment: which statement would be true? @EeveeTrainer

Comment: so isnt my answer correct casue if Q and P were mutually exclusive their would be no X's in common in the box,but since they are their not mutually exclusive @EeveeTrainer

Answer (score 1):

> the answer is D,P and Q are not mutually exclusive because they dont have a disjoint set

the answer is d., because P and Q are not *disjoint sets*.  That is, their *intersection is not empty*, so there are outcomes where both events may occur.  The occurrence of either event does not exclude the occurrence of the other.

(PS: The adjective "disjoint" applies to a *collection* of plural sets.  There is no such thing as ***a** disjoint set*.)